# Upload txt files to hyperledger composer and associate them with an asset

Tags: upload, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I think this should happen on the client side (NodeJS) to maybe convert the file to   a base64 string and then upload it. 
I would like to create a Transaction that allows the Client (that will mainly talk to the REST server) to upload a .TXT File (an maybe another similar column based file) to the composer blockchain (to make it immutable) and then associate the file with an Asset.

How can this be done?

Thanks in advacen.

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer. You need to convert the file-contents to a hash and you can store it. You can consider using the strategy IPFS follows.

Comment: Hi. So I need to convert the file-contents to a hash and then store it. I know that there are some rules and guidelins on how to convert them. Do you know precisely or maybe someone else? And as I have seen Hyperledger Fabric does not support IPFS natively.